# Asp.Net MVC Large Files Upload using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to upload multiple into ASP.NET MVC controller. I'm appending multiple files to a FormData and send them in one XMLHttpRequest, And I'm using IISExpress.
By searching on google I have changed the web.config as following:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647"/>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I also try to use "PUT" instead of "POST" on opening XMLHttpRequest as following:

```
 xhr.open("PUT", myForm.action, true);
```

but I still can not make a request more than 30 MB !! I really need to make this work, so I hope someone helps me out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove async 'true' from xhr.open function